# Inserir HTML via jQuery (Chat)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Galera, estou a desenvolver um Chat com Faye. No back-end tudo normal. Fucionando perfeitamente, mas estou com problema bobo: não consigo inserir as mensagens para visualização. Vou explicar melhor:

Quando recupero as mensagens eu insiro em uma `<div class="panel_msg>`, dentro de uma tabela (sei que não é a alternativa mais viável, mas é apenas um teste). Daí usando a função `html()` ele jQuery ele faz o trabalho normamente, mas quando outro cliente envia uma mensagem ele não adiciona outra tabela na div, ele apenas adiciona o texto junto ao texto já existente.

Como faço para ir adicionando tabela após tabela?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iCube &bull; Beta</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/faye/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- Carrega Styles css -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/campo_texto.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <!-- Em breve -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Fim menu -->
    <!-- Campo de texto -->
    <div class="campo_texto">
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="texto"></td>
                <td><button id="enviar">Enviar</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Fim campo de texto -->
    <div class="panel_msg">
         <!-- As mensagens veem aqui -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:8000/faye');

$(function () {
    $('#enviar').click(function(){

         var mensagem = $('#texto').val();

         client.publish('/faye', { 'texto': mensagem });

            client.subscribe('/faye', function (message) {

                $('.panel_msg').html("
                <table cellspacing=\"12\" > 
                    <tr>
                        <td class=\"msg_txt\">"+message.texto+"
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <table>");
            }); 

            $('.panel_msg').html("
            <table cellspacing=\"12\" >
                <tr>
                    <td class=\"msg_txt\">"+message.texto+"</td>
                </tr>
            </table>");
      });   
});
```

PS: estou enviando um JSON ali, a forma como recupero está correta?

Comment: Acho que tens de usar o `.append()` mas sem ver o teu código não posso dizer com certeza. Junta o código à pergunta para podermos ajudar mais...

Comment: Poste o código `html` e `jquery` para facilitar o entendimento amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `.html()` substitui conteúdo, o método `.append()` acrescenta conteúdo.

Mais ainda, olhando o teu código parece-me mais lógico ires acrescentando linhas à tabela, e não novas tabelas a cada mensagem. Assim sugiro teres no HTML:

```
<div class="panel_msg">
    <table cellspacing="12">
        <!-- As mensagens veem aqui -->
    </table>
</div>
```

e no JavaScript:

```
var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:8000/faye');

function novaLinha(texto) {
    var tr = $('<tr />');
   var td = $('<td />', {
        text: texto,
        class: 'msg_txt'
    });
    return tr.append(td);
}

$('#enviar').click(function() {
    var mensagem = $('#texto').val();
    client.publish('/faye', {
        'texto': mensagem
    });
    client.subscribe('/faye', function(message) {
        $('.panel_msg table').append(novaLinha(message));
    });
});
```

Comment: Sua resposta me pareceu bem mais explicativa. Obg!

Comment: E ainda assim ganhou -1. Tem alguém trolando por aí

Answer (score -1):

Tenta assim, utilizando `append`

```
var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:8000/faye');
$(function () {
    $('#enviar').click(function(){

         var mensagem = $('#texto').val();

         client.publish('/faye', { 'texto': mensagem });

            client.subscribe('/faye', function (message) {

                $('.panel_msg').append("
                <table cellspacing=\"12\" > 
                    <tr>
                        <td class=\"msg_txt\">"+message.texto+"
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <table>");
            }); 

            $('.panel_msg').append("
            <table cellspacing=\"12\" >
                <tr>
                    <td class=\"msg_txt\">"+message.texto+"</td>
                </tr>
            </table>");
      });   
});
```

Comment: Opa! Probleminha resolvido =) Obg @JhonatanSimões

Comment: Acho que esta resposta tem problemas... **a)** quebras de linha em javascript dão erro de sintaxe; **b)** como está vão sendo acrescentadas 2 mensagens de cada vez; **c)** tem um `});` a mais entre os dois `$('.panel_msg').append`

Comment: Mais dai é problema na Lógica de negócio do usuário, que não tem qualquer influência na resposta. E o @Mike disse que deu certo.

Comment: Não leves a mal o meu comentário, comentei porque acho que pode ser melhorada, é só [edit]. Se achares algo errado na minha resposta podes explicar também, é melhor ter votos negativos com explicação do que sem explicação :)

Comment: Com certeza mano, vc tem razão... entretanto não posso mudar a forma como o usuário que perguntou programou, me abstive apenas na pergunta, até porque nem sei como isso está estilizado na tela, talvez alterando o html dele, ou as tags pode ser que tenha um impacto negativo no estilo que ele aplicou em seu projeto.

Comment: @JhonatanSimões mesmo tentando usar o código dele isso dá erro de sintaxe. Tem pelo menos de estar assim: https://jsfiddle.net/rycwtn2y/1/